Cast from VLC on windows to DLNA renderer
I am using VLC 3.0.20 under windows and want to cast my audio (music) to a DLNA renderer on my network.  I can do this using MS Windows Media Player (works fine), but I want to use VLC
In VLC under PlayBack>Renderer I only see < LOCAL > and "scanning".  Why will my DLNA renderer not appear?
I found under Tools>Playlist>Service Discovery there is an option to add "services discovery modules" but I can't find what goes in there, or anything about this, in cases that's important.
